# Doubts with for loop in Unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix, for-loop

Sorry if its sounds dumb but I'm currently studying for an exam to apply for a job (administrative one) and I learnt about [java](/questions/tagged/java), [php](/questions/tagged/php), [python](/questions/tagged/python) but not much about [unix](/questions/tagged/unix) scripts. I can see it's very similar to [php](/questions/tagged/php) in structure and I have many questions about it .

One of them is this loop, what does it do and why does it output `b*`?

```
for var in b*
   echo $var
done
```

I tried this code and the terminal output was `b*`, Why does this code answer me with text (in this case, `b*`) or does something else happen?

Comment: The code you show gives a syntax error.  You omitted the `do`, which is required for all shell loops.  PHP does not behave particularly like a shell.  Maybe you are fooled by the `$` prefix:  in PHP that is part of the variable name, in bash it is a unary operator to give the value.  So `$` is not used on the left-side of an assignment in bash, but is in PHP (PHP was influenced more by Perl and C than shells).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A for loop in shell scripting takes each whitespace separated string from the input and assigns it to the variable given, and runs the code once for each value. In your case `b*` is the input and `$var` is the assigned variable.

The shell will also perform *expansion* on the input. Basically, the `*` acts like a wildcard for any part of a file name. So if you have files beginning with b in the current directory, those will get looped over:

```
$ ls
bean.java bean.class readme.txt
$ for var in b*; do echo $var; done
bean.java
bean.class
```

If however you don't have any files beginning with b (so that your pattern `b*` doesn't match anything) the pattern will remain unexpanded:

```
$ rm bean.*
$ ls
readme.txt
$ for var in b*; do echo $var; done
b*
```

Comment: Oh i see , that makes sense.
When the terminal answered me with " b* " only, i thought it was like String value in Java.

Thank you so much. Never is too late to learn .

Comment: Though you should quote the variable; `echo "$var"` with double quotes.

Comment: ... and, since you are teaching globbing, use `echo *` rather than `ls`.